# "Teams members" or "Team members" (considering we are talking about 2 teams)?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, grammatical-number, possessives, possessive-s-vs-of

In the context of we having 2 Teams: team 1, and team 2. I want to refer to the members of all the teams we have. Should I say "Teams members" or do I still have to use the singular of "team", like "Team members"?

Comment: Compound nouns in English are pluralised by adding "s" to the last word so "team member"->"team members". If that's what you're asking. There are a lot of questions on the subject but I can't immediately find an exact duplicate (there are a lot about pluralising multi-word product names, and about "security trader" vs "securities trader", which I don't think is quite the same question). If you had more than one door key, you wouldn't say "doors keys", would you?

Comment: We say "orange groves" not "oranges groves" even if each grove has more than one orange in it.

Comment: If you want to refer to all the employees (or whatever they are) together, and it doesn't matter who belongs to which team, why use the phrase *team(s) members* at all? Why not just say *employees*?

Comment: A synthetic example, just to answer your question: Imagine a game.

"East teams members begin the game with red cards, but West teams members begin the game with green cards. There are 8 teams, 4 East teams and 4 West teams."

You suggest "East players begin the game with red cards, but West players begin the game with green cards ...".

Nice, there are pros and cons. For an instruction manual, maybe you want to make sure there is not confussion at all, and be the most precise possible.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments to your question indicate, *team members* is used regardless of the number of teams.

It is ambiguous compared to other languages that would pluralize *team* in that case. If you need to specify that the members don't belong to the same team, you might say one of the following :

- *the teams' members*
- *the members of the teams*.

> *The moves to keep the teams’ members safe come attached with multiple costs to the franchises.* Washington Post, Feb 2020